# Are there any downsides to choosing not to join threads in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a program that uses multiple threads to brute force the decryption of some encrypted string. The main thread has a channel, and the sender is cloned and sent to each thread. When a thread finds an answer, it sends it to the receiver which is in the main thread.

In this program I am not joining the threads, instead I use the blocking call `sender.recv()` to suspend the main thread until a single other thread finishes.

My hope is, once this call finishes, the main thread will return and all the other worker threads will be terminated.

Is this a poor design choice? Are there drawbacks of not having some  condition in the other threads which would cause them to return when the solution has been discovered? Is it okay/safe to rely on the compiler to clean up my threads before they've technically finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's no cleanup to be done, what you've done is mostly harmless. I'm assuming your worker thread looks something like this right now.

```
fn my_thread() {
  // ... lots of hard work ...
  channel.send(my_result);
}
```

and if that's the case, then "I received the result" and "the other thread is terminated" are very similar events, and the difference of "this function returned" is probably irrelevant. But suppose someone comes along and changes the code to look like this.

```
fn my_thread() {
  // ... lots of hard work ...
  channel.send(my_result);
  do_cleanup_stuff();
}
```

Now `do_cleanup_stuff()` might not get a chance to run, if your main thread terminates before `my_thread` does. If that cleanup function is important, that could cause problems. And it could be more subtle than that. If any local variable in `my_thread` holds a file handle or an open TCP stream or any other object with a nontrivial `Drop` implementation, that value may not get a chance to `Drop` properly if you don't `join` the thread.

So it's probably best practice to `join` everything, even if it's just a final step at the end of your `main`.

Comment: But imagine each thread is searching for a solution using an algorithm that operates in O(n!), where the only break condition arises if the solution is found and only one thread can (but is guaranteed to) find the solution -- in this case joining each thread could significantly increase the program runtime.

Also, each thread is pure and doesn't do any I/O stuff, and for the purposes of this program I can assume there's no manual cleanup necessary. In this scenario, is there any downside in not joining the threads?